# why can't you escape with consecutive calls to .text() JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm escaping form input with jQuery as follows

```
var escapedStr = $('<div>').text(formInput).html();
```

It works fine and happy.

But why doesn't the following work?

```
var escapedStr = $('<div>').text(formInput).text();
```

If `var formInput = '<h1>'`, then `$('<div>').text(formInput).text();` should insert an escaped `h1` tag into a `div`, then grab out the escaped text itself? Instead, the second `text()` grabs an HTML tag that renders when added to the DOM.

What's happening here? Can someone explain? Here is a JS fiddle with various examples. I'm confused about the second case. https://jsfiddle.net/EmOnTheWeb/72sbypg7/9/

Comment: Why would you expect `.text()` to return html markup?

Comment: Simply put, `.text()` function returns what you _see_. After you do `div.text('<h1>')` you can actually see "<h1>" on the website, don't you? So that's what is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what this code does with the source text `<h1>am I rendering?`.

```
var escapedStr = $('<div>').text(formInput).html();
```

1. Insert `formInput` *as text* into the `div`:

This yields:

```
<div>&lt;h1&gt;am I rendering?</div>
```

2. Get the *HTML* content of the `div`:

This yields:

```
&lt;h1&gt;am I rendering?
```

If you replace`.html()` with `.text()`, this means "get the text content of the div." So it should equal the same thing you put *in* as text.

```
<h1>am I rendering?
```

It can seem a little confusing, but that's only because your text *is* HTML. The behavior is correct. Perhaps these methods were confusingly named. Here's an alternative way to think of them:

```
div.text()    ~= htmlDecode(div.innerHTML)
div.text(str) ~= div.innerHTML = htmlEncode(str)
div.html()    ~= div.innerHTML
div.html(str) ~= div.innerHTML = str
```

(note, the above is not quite accurate, since `text()` actually gives you the concatenated text nodes of the element and all its children, but it's correct for an HTML element with only text and no children)

Answer (score 0):

In your JS Fiddle example, the second example only *looks* like the escaping is failing because you're using the jQuery [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

The jQuery DOM manipulation methods expect whole DOM nodes, so it's automatically inserting the closing `</h1>` tag when you call [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
var str = '<h1>am I rendering?'; 

/* 
  text(str) calls document.createTextNode(str), which escapes the markup
  html() gets the innerHTML property of the div which at this point is "&lt;h1&gt;hello"
*/
var attemptEsc = $('<div>').text(str).html(); 
$('body').append('1. insert with text() grab out with html() gives: ' +attemptEsc);  

/* 
  text(str) calls document.createTextNode(str), which escapes the markup
  text() gets the textContent property of the div, which at this point is "<h1>hello" 
  because textContent unescapes HTML entities  
*/ 
var attemptEsc1 = $('<div>').text(str).text();
$('body').append('<br> 2. insert with text() grab out with text() gives: '+attemptEsc1); 

/* 
  html(str) sets the innerHTML of the div, attempting to create complete DOM nodes
  html() gets the innerHTML property of the div which at this point is "<h1>hello</h1>"
*/ 
var attemptEsc2 = $('<div>').html(str).text(); 
$('body').append('<br> 3. insert with html() grab out with text() gives: ' +attemptEsc2); 

/* 
  html(str) sets the innerHTML of the div, attempting to create complete DOM nodes
  text() gets the textContent property of the div, which at this point is "hello"
*/ 
var attemptEsc3 = $('<div>').html(str).html();
$('body').append('<br> 4. insert with html() grab out with html() gives: '+attemptEsc3);
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. I guess my question wasn't why a closing tag is automatically added, but why .text() called on `$('<div>').text(str)` returns unescaped characters, and seems to reverse the work of the initial text() call, while .html() returns the escaped character entities.

Comment: After `$('<div>').text(str);` we have `<div>&lt;h1&gt;am I rendering?</div>` and if we call html() on the <div> it returns `&lt;h1&gt;am I rendering?`  yet if we call text() to get the text out of the div it returns `<h1>am I rendering?`

Comment: No problem! You have to navigate the jQuery source code to see what standard DOM methods and properties it ends up using. I updated the answer to show what each jQuery method is doing in the chained calls.